# Require custom file in Rails' scss manifest file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Is it possible to somehow require a scss file in the manifest by using a helper method?

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require '<%= current_tenant.name %>'
 */
```

This currently throws a `couldn't find file '<%= current_tenant.name %>'` error. I tried renaming `application.scss` to `application.scss.erb` but still won't work.

Comment: well in this case I guess your helper method must be defined in intializers

Comment: https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#invoking-ruby-with-erb
This may help you

Comment: I've done this already (tried with .erb file extension) and both `<%=` and string interpolation. Neither works in the manifest.

Comment: make sure file name is `.css.erb` and restarting server once is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me
in `application.css.erb`

```
 *= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
 *= require "<%= p"dataTables/jquery.dataTables" %>"
 *
```

I even tried like this

```
 *= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
 *= require "<%= p"dataTables/jquery.dataTables" + (12*12).to_s %>"
 *
```

output I got is

```
 *= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/.
 *= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
 *= require "dataTables/jquery.dataTables144"
 *
```

so may be you should try like this. You need to wrap your embeded ruby code by double quotes

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require "<%= current_tenant.name %>"
 */
```

Comment: Doesn't work in Rails 4. Still get a `Sprockets::FileNotFound`

Comment: does it still show the `<%= .. %>` in the error message?

Comment: Yes. Here is what I'm using... `require "<%= current_tenant.name %>"`